# Logrotate script not running

Tags: linux, bash, unix, logging, logrotate

I have the following logrotate script

```
/path/to/folder {
   daily
   rotate 30
   notifempty
   sharedscripts
   copytruncate
   compress
   dateext


   preremove
     if file --mime-type "$1" | grep -q gzip$; then
          mkdir -p /path/to/archive/folder && cp $1 $_
     fi
   endscript
}
```

---

- What I am trying to achieve:-

  *Before removal of a log file after a retention of 30 days, copy to another folder.*

I am running this logstash config on debug mode

```
logrotate -d $CONFIG_FILE
```

By the looks of the logs, the rotation is working fine, but it does not even run the `preremove` script. 
I have not run this config on live yet, as I wanted to test it before doing that.

> logrotate version 3.8.6

Comment: Notice that `preremove` runs `/bin/sh`, where you might have no `$_` available (at least [POSIX sh](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) doesn't seem to require it). Also, make sure to quote `"$1"` everywhere, and single quote `'gzip$'`. Try adding debug output like `echo blah >> /tmp/debug` to see if the script gets run.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I tried replacing `$_` with the `path/to/archived/folder` - still did not work. 
I also tried `echo "testing"` in the preremove script. It does not seem to be running.

Comment: I'm not sure where standard output for `logrotate` goes – did you try redirecting it to a file for the `echo` debug statement?

Comment: @BenjaminW. It does not seem to be going into the `preremove` script. 
Putting an echo outside the `preremove` block throws an error `unknown option 'echo'`. But when it is inside `preremove` block it does not throw that error.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Has the `preremove` not running issue have to do something with running it on debug mode? I cannot use this script without dry running it and testing it.

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. I'd try running it in non-debug mode on some test files instead of the real logs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether you're asking why preremove isn't running, or whether your script looks OK.

#### Preremove, and how to test

I don't believe that logrotate will ever run a `preremove` script if it's not removing files (per `-d`). I set up a test case and ran it under `strace`. The `logrotate -d` found the files that needed to be removed and wrote that it would have removed them, but did not run the `preremove` code. Honestly this makes sense to me, and is what I expect, since the `preremove` could do things as damaging as the deletion itself.

To perform a test, I think you need to reproduce your live environment in another directory and just actually run it. Don't use full size files, just use dummy files with a few lines. Create a script to build your test folder, so you can reproduce the test easily. Use `touch` to set timestamps. For example:

```
for n in $(seq 1 30); do
    cp test.log test.log.$n
    gzip test.log.$n
    touch -d "now - $n day" test.log.$n.gz
done
```

#### The script itself

- `grep -q gzip$` is wrong. The `$` will disappear in the shell parse. You need to enclose this in single quotes.
- As someone else wrote, I would not expect `$_` to work. Repeat the directory name, or use a variable in the script.
- I don't think you need the `\` escapes at EOL, as suggested.
- You probably want `cp -p`, as someone suggested.
- If your files are large, the `cp` will be slow. If your archive is on the same filesystem, consider using `ln` (not `ln -s`!) instead. This will be instant.
- Using `file --mime-type` probably works fine, but frankly I'd just base it on the file name in this case, since logrotate will reliably append `.gz` on any file for which `file` would return `gzip`. `expr "$1" : '.*gz$'` will give a nonzero number as standard output for any `$1` that ends in `.gz`. It will give exactly the number 0 as standard output for a filename that does not end in `.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing line continuation escapes as seen in [some examples](https://jahboite.co.uk/blog/2016-03-12-archive-log-files-using-logrotate-preremove.html)

```
preremove
    # debug line
    systemd-cat -t "rot-pre-rm" echo "preremove block, file: $1"
    if file --mime-type "$1" | grep -q gzip$; then \
        cp -p "$1" /path/to/archive/syslog/; \
    fi; \
endscript
```

Comment: Does not seem to be working running them in the `-d` mode

Comment: you can also put the code is a shell script and invoke it.

Comment: It seems as though the `preremove` block is not even run. 
I tried invoking the snippet within `preremove` putting it another shell script with some `echo`. Does not seem to run.

Comment: Add `systemd-cat echo "preremove block"` *outside* the if-else, then check with `journalctl`. If systemd is not pesent on your host, use just an echo. May be the `if`conditions are not met.

Answer (score 0):

I think your condition itself is not coming **true** can you put echo before preremove to debug. Try to execute your if condition manually and see.

```
# file --mime-type * | grep -i *.1
audit.log.1: text/plain
# file --mime-type * | grep -i *.1$
# file --mime-type * | grep -q *.1$
# file --mime-type * | grep -q *.1
```